# How to fix my linked list code from displaying: AttributeError: 'linked_list' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to follow a tutorial on creating an empty linked list but I am coming across an error that I don't understand. I am new to Classes in python so don't understand what it means when it says object has no attribute head when I run the code

```
class node:
    def _init_(self,data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class linked_list:
    def _init_(self):
        self.head = node()

    def append(self,data):
        new_node = node(data)
        cur = self.head
        while cur.next!=None:
            cur = cur.next
        cur.next = new_node

    def length(self):
        cur = self.head
        total = 0
        while cur.next!=None:
            total+=1
            cur = cur.next
        return total

    def display(self):
        elems = []
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next!=None:
            cur_node=cur_node.next
            elems.append(cur_node.data)
        print (elems)

my_list = linked_list()

my_list.display()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor's name is incorrect: it should be `__init__` (2 underscores) instead of `_init_`.

```
class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = node()
```

Python thinks that `_init_` is just another method, not a constructor. Thus, the assignment of `self.head` never happened.

Comment: Thanks, as I said I'm new